# Passing a variable to an Insert Statement in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sqlplus

I want create  a trigger that every time I have an insert on a table
it will perform another insert on another table in a differt schema.

The problem is that I want pass a variable that contain che schema.table to the query for the insert.
But when i try to do, I have an error. This is what I've written:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_TEST
AFTER INSERT ON MYTABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
test VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
test := "myschema.mytable2"

Insert into test (a, b, c)
VALUES(:new.a,:new.b,:new.c);
END;
```

How can i correctly pass the string value of the variable to the query? Is it possible?

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`) to pass an identifier into a query..

Comment: Thanks for your info. Is it possible to have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a variable for a table name or a column name, you need to use dynamic SQL for this. By keeping the bind variables in your statement and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE you can workaround that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_TEST
AFTER INSERT ON MYTABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
test VARCHAR2(128);
BEGIN
test := "myschema.mytable2"

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Insert into ' || test || ' (a, b, c) VALUES(:1,:2,:3)' USING :new.a,:new.b,:new.c;
END;
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation about this code, what did you do to solve the problem?  What was the issue in the Question asker's code?  Low quality answers are subject to deletion.

Comment: I added clarification on how the problem can be resolved and the way I fixed it.